# APIGen neon config file format

Tags: php, phpdoc, apigen

I'm trying to run APIGen v4 but I can't get the config file to parse properly. Does anyone have a working example of a APIGen neon config file which works with APIGen v4?

Answer (score 1):

Found an example here which did the trick - https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/499423/apigen-neon-file-example-(apigen-neon)